# GapDebug: Can not connect to the server

Tags: cordova, android-5.0-lollipop, gapdebug

I got an Android update yesterday, which installed Lollipop on my Note 3 (So I went from 4.4 to 5.0). After the update, GapDebug stopped working and it now shows this message:

> Can not connect to the server

I'm using GapDebug 2015 update 1.3, Chrome 43.0.2357.124 on a Mac Yosemite and as mentioned, Android 5.0

PS: I've tested it with a Galaxy S4, also with Android 5.0, and it had the same issue. On the other hand, a Galaxy Tab 4 with Android 4.4 and a Lenovo Tab with 4.4 smoothly worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the latest GapDebug update 2015 2.1, this issue was fixed.